# Why isn't AngularJS working with elements that are appended to the page after page load?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, scope

Say I have an area on the page that looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li id="li_1" ng-controller="FooBarCtrl as foobar" ng-init="setup_stuff(1)">
       <button id="button_1" ng-click="foobar.doButtonyThings">Weeeeeeee!</button>
    </li>
    <li id="li_2" ng-controller="FooBarCtrl as foobar" ng-init="setup_stuff(2)">
        <button id="button_2" ng-click="foobar.doButtonyThings">Weeeeeeee!</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Each of these list items needs to have its own object associated with it.

Now, say in some javascript file I want to add another list item to this list.  I can figure out that the next "index" in the list is 3, so I make all the element changes in the javascript, and then append it to the list.

This works, and the element is appended and all of the HTML for it in the DOM looks good when it's appended.

```
<ul>
    <li id="li_1" ng-controller="FooBarCtrl as foobar" ng-init="setup_stuff(1)">
       <button id="button_1" ng-click="foobar.doButtonyThings(1)">Weeeeeeee!</button>
    </li>
    <li id="li_2" ng-controller="FooBarCtrl as foobar" ng-init="setup_stuff(2)">
        <button id="button_2" ng-click="foobar.doButtonyThings(2)">Weeeeeeee!</button>
    </li>
    <li id="li_3" ng-controller="FooBarCtrl as foobar" ng-init="setup_stuff(3)">
        <button id="button_3" ng-click="foobar.doButtonyThings(3)">Weeeeeeee!</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The issue I'm facing is that, while the HTML looks correct, the angular for the new element never actually gets "hooked up".  In other words, no angular works for appended elements.  For the first two, since they were there on page load, clicking their respective buttons will call the doButtonyThings() function.  But for appended elements, nothing happens.

Unfortunately restructuring the code so that appends aren't happening in outside javascript files isn't something I have control over, so I need to figure out how to make it work this way, even if not best practice.

Is there some extra step I need to take in order to "hook up" appended elements so that angular works with them?

---

EDIT:

Here's the logic being used to add a "line" to the list.  I have a hidden template list item in the DOM that I use to append a new list item.  This is actual code, so it won't really link up with the foo bar stuff above.

> NOTE:  this is *not* Angular controlled code.  This is vanilla javascript.

```
addLine:function(lineNumber)
{
    var lineTemplate = document.getElementsByClassName('template__line')[0];
    var newLine = lineTemplate.cloneNode(true);

    //replace template sections
    newLine.className = 'clearfix ng-scope';
    newLine.innerHTML = newLine.innerHTML.replace(/__lineNumber__/g, lineNumber.toString());
    newLine.style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('quick-order__body').appendChild(newLine);
}
```

Comment: Angular "binds" your HTML when it loads. If you add HTML later, you need to tell Angular that there is new stuff to "hook up" to, look at mcgraphix answer. As this shows you what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you append new html that includes directives (such as ng-click) you need to use the $compile service (which you will need to inject) to make Angular aware of it:

```
 $compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

We would need some of your javascript code to go on to give you a more concrete example for your use case. It may be that you are better off with an array that you iterate over with ng-repeat to spit out your html. That way when the array is changed by adding/removing, the html will automatically be updated.

Comment: sure, I'll add in the logic I'm using to append an element.

Comment: Can this $compile be triggered from a vanilla javascript file, as in the Edit to my post above?  I don't really have enough pull to change code structure.. I'm kinda stuck with the structure of previous developers.

Comment: How are you triggering that javascript? It is a little weird to be mixing angular and non-angular code in this way.

Comment: Tell me about it... basically they're completely isolated.  So on a buttonpress, I'm calling someVanillaJSObject.addLine().  This appends the line, but the existing angular doesn't catch it.  To make it make *slightly* more sense, I was told AngularJS needed to be removed completely from a page EXCEPT for this one thing... because logic.

Comment: Technically you could get a reference on the DOM node that was created after running your non-angular code, and then just call: $compile(angular.element(yourNewElement))($scope)

Comment: BTW - You may need to call $scope.$apply() after compile. You'd have to test it though. I've never quite done anything just like this before.